# How does the link token return a public token? Public token = request.body.publictoken?

Tags: node.js, plaid

1. Could you explain how and where in the code the link_token returns a public token?

```
app.post('/api/create_link_token', async function (request, response) {
  const configs = {
    user: {
      // This should correspond to a unique id for the current user.
      client_user_id: 'user-id',
    },
    client_name: 'Plaid Quickstart',
    products: PLAID_PRODUCTS,
    country_codes: PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES,
    language: 'en',
  };

  if (PLAID_REDIRECT_URI !== '') {
    configs.redirect_uri = PLAID_REDIRECT_URI;
  }

  if (PLAID_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME !== '') {
    configs.android_package_name = PLAID_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME;
  }
  try {
    const createTokenResponse = await client.linkTokenCreate(configs);
    console.log('Create Token response below')
    prettyPrintResponse(createTokenResponse.data);
    response.json(createTokenResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    prettyPrintResponse(error);
    return response.json(formatError(error.response));
  }
});
```

According to Plaid Docs:
The /link/token/create endpoint creates a link_token, which is required as a parameter when initializing Link. Once Link has been initialized, it returns a public_token, which can then be exchanged for an access_token via /item/public_token/exchange as part of the main Link flow.

2. How is PUBLIC_TOKEN= request.body.public_token? How did the public token get in the request.body?

```
app.post('/api/set_access_token', async function (request, response, next) {
// Im inquiring about the line right below//
  PUBLIC_TOKEN = request.body.public_token;
  console.log("after", PUBLIC_TOKEN)
  try {
    const tokenResponse = await client.itemPublicTokenExchange({
      public_token: PUBLIC_TOKEN,
    });
    prettyPrintResponse(tokenResponse.data);
    ACCESS_TOKEN = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
    ITEM_ID = tokenResponse.data.item_id;
    response.json({
      access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
      item_id: ITEM_ID,
      error: null,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    prettyPrintResponse(error);
    return response.json(formatError(error.response));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The link token is getting returned in

`response.json(createTokenResponse.data);`

This code is using the Express framework -- you can read a little bit more about it here: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/json

On the client side, `createTokenResponse.data` is received as `data` and the `link_token` is extracted from it:

```
`          $.post("/api/create_link_token", {}, function (data) {
            ...
            localStorage.setItem("link_token", data.link_token);
            handler = Plaid.create({
              token: data.link_token,
```

or, in the React Quickstart, in frontend/src/App.tsx:

```
  const generateToken = useCallback(
    async (paymentInitiation) => {
      const path = paymentInitiation
        ? "/api/create_link_token_for_payment"
        : "/api/create_link_token";
      const response = await fetch(path, {
        method: "POST",
      });
      ...
      const data = await response.json();
        ...
        dispatch({ type: "SET_STATE", state: { linkToken: data.link_token } });
      }
      localStorage.setItem("link_token", data.link_token); //to use later for Oauth
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
```

2. The `public_token` is set during the call to `/api/set_access/token`, here:

```
handler = Plaid.create({
              token: data.link_token,
              onSuccess: function (public_token) {
                $.post(
                  "/api/set_access_token",
                  {
                    public_token: public_token
                  },
```

Or, if you're using the React Quickstart, this code is in

frontend/src/Components/Link/index.tsx:

```
const onSuccess = React.useCallback(
    (public_token: string) => {
      // send public_token to server
      const setToken = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("/api/set_access_token", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
          },
          body: `public_token=${public_token}`,
        });
```